# Exclude folder in SVN Export using Tortoise SVN

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have a folder structure in SVN as follows:

```
-> Root
   -> A
   -> B
   -> C
```

I am version controlling all folders (A,B and C) as I want to track changes.

When I export however, I only want the A and C folders to export, not the B.

I could just export the whole root project, then delete folder B. But I'd like to know if there's a way to set this up so I don't have to delete it every time using TortoiseSVN?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No possibility to do that, cause export exports everything.

Answer (score 1):

You might get the result you want, under Windows at least, by "exporting" through the Repo-browser. Start the TortoiseSVN Repo-browser. There, you can select multiple, separate folders (in the right-hand pane), right-click and drag them to a Windows folder that you have created in advance (on your desktop, perhaps). Drop the folders, and select Copy Here at the context-menu prompt. Voila.